# Update is not applicable to the equipment, Windows Server 2016

Tags: windows, windows-server-2016, windows-update

I have problems to execute windows updates through independent windows installers.

The equipement show message that say: The update is not applicable in this equipement.

S.O Windows Server 2016

Comment: Please don't repost the same question. If you have additional information, you may edit your existing question.